# how to upload an excel file in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i try to upload  excel file in odoo 10 but an SQL message error 
[image]

So how can i resolve this problem please ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it that the check constraint res_partner_check_name fails. 
Maybe the name already exists?
Or the name is empty?
Do you have all the required fields set?

You can try to export an existing row, so you can see which fields are required.

Comment: Thnks , but how i can do Export, i can't find an export Button ?

Comment: Go to the list/tree view > select a row > click on more (middle top of the screen) > click on export.

Comment: It's work , and the import to it's work for me thank you a lot friend ;)